# batch - multi threading artisan servers

Tags: php, windows, laravel, batch-file, cmd

The question is straight forward, how can I run two php artisan commands at the same time?

I have two commands:

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80`
and
`php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`

If I run them in seperated cmd windows, it works, but I would like to have them in just one cmd window.

Is this possible? I currently have this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting DigiCoach Application
TITLE Digicoach Console application
ECHO This might take a while...
CMD /T:70 /b php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
CMD /T:70 /b php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

Comment: try installing this ( http://cmder.net/ ) you can open multiple tabs in one window, just like chrome.

Comment: That's not what my question is... The ideal situation here would be to have some kind of exe that I could run and that then runs a bunch of commands (multi-threaded) instead of me, manually typing each command in a new terminal window...

Answer (score 0):

If you start them they will run in parralel:

```
Start "" php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
Start "" php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

*Edit*. As per @Aacini's comment the `/b` switch might be useful to what you require as it starts both commands without opening a new window.

```
Start /b "" php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
Start /b "" php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

I would however not recommend this as the output will not be what you expect. Something like calling something as simple as 2 ping commands can give an output that seems to be of an unknown language as the one commands output interferes with the others.

Comment: Yes, that far was I already too, but how could I "merge" the output of these into one (customized) cmd window? (that you can't close except with pressing the X and a confirmation?

Comment: That is not going to happen in a single window.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility of making a Dotnet console application that does this?

Comment: You really don't want to have them both spewing to the same console, unless everything they output is a line at time. Even then, not all applications play nice with each other when it comes to sharing the screen.

Comment: @aacini I am not 100% sure it is what OP wants, but yes you are correct it might be what he wants. I updated my answer.